# Trying to understand PHP template, Plates

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, trying to understand how to use a simple template system with PHP, I like "Plates", mainly because it claims to be a template system, not a template language, but the documentation is kind of confusing.
As an example where this code "controller" leaves? Is it a another PHP file?

```
// Create new Plates instance
$templates = new League\Plates\Engine('/path/to/templates');

// Render a template
echo $templates->render('profile', ['name' => 'Jonathan']);
```

Shouldn't this code "profile.php" call the controller file somewhere?

**profile.php**

```
<?php $this->layout('template', ['title' => 'User Profile']) ?>

  <h1>User Profile</h1>
  <p>Hello, <?=$this->e($name)?></p>
```

The template file:

**template.php**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title><?=$this->e($title)?></title>
  </head>
  <body>

  <?=$this->section('content')?>

  </body>
 </html>
```

Does anyone have a better code sample using "Plates" in PHP where I can see how this template system works?

Thank you!

Comment: based on your first code, since you have it from the example page, you have `profile` there, this piece of code `echo $templates->render('profile', ['name' => 'Jonathan']);` renders the `profile.php` with the parameter `name` and the value of `Jonathan`

Comment: A controller is, simply said, the php file which brings everything together; your data (model) and templates (views). It is used in the Model-View-Controller (MVC) design/architectural pattern. Google it (there is no single authorative source, otherwise I would have linked to it ;))

Comment: Shouldn't the profile.php file have some sort of this: 
require "controler.php";? It doesn't make any sense to me,  it seems that these sample code are out of order.

Comment: Can you explain how, because I don't see any call from this files that has the code you are mentioning.

Answer (score 3):

The example in the Plates doc is pretty good and simple. The way I see it - you might have an MVC controller or you might not; the code in question may reside in a simple script (lets say index.php for the sake of clarity). Lets imagine the site structure looks like:

- /index.php
- /templates/ folder
- /templates/profile.php
- /templates/template.php

The code in index.php becomes:

```
// Create new Plates instance
$templates = new League\Plates\Engine('/templates');

// Render a template
echo $templates->render('profile', ['name' => 'Jonathan']);
```

You might have it in an MVC controller, but that is totally different topic.

Comment: The rest (profile and template) are the same as yours.

Comment: Yeah index.php. Change the path in $templates = new League\Plates\Engine('/templates'); with the good one (try complete system path as a starter)

Comment: I installed Plates using "Composer", should this code:
{
    "require": {
        "league/plates": "3.*"
    }
}

be inserted into index.php?

Comment: You should include vendor/autoload.php

Comment: Add vendor/autoload.php to the index.php?

Comment: I am also confused by this path: 
$templates = new League\Plates\Engine('/templates'); Is the path  League\Plates\Engine relative to where it got installed or is it as is? Anyway could you show me how this index.php file would look like as far as this example?

Comment: Yes, vendor/autoload to index.php and about the path in League\Plates\Engine try the absolute filesystem path to templates folder

Comment: The path for the template file I understand, this string "League\Plates\Engine ", is it as it is?

Comment: This is namespace it should stay that way .... the path is something like /var/www/htdocs/templates on Linux or lets say C:\Program Files\Lamp\htdocs\templates on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to try a pure php templating engine too so I tried out Plates as well.  It is simple.  I like simple solutions for simple problems.  They are faster to implement.

If you are new to php using Plates can be a great way to start to write 'cleaner' code with very little additional investment of your time.

Because you are new to PHP there is a bit of background detail you need to understand first.  Then I think it will be clear.

The example [here](https://platesphp.com/getting-started/simple-example/) is not so great in that the paths are not that useful.  Assume they intend to show that the fully qualified path is required.  A better example would have used something like:

```
$templates = new Engine(__DIR__ . '/templates');
```

where the templates directory is a sub-directory of the current folder that the presenter or controller may be in.

Since templates are central to presentation, it is my opinion that presenter is a better name for the class that will be using the templates but a lot of people use controller because of the popularity of mvc.

"\League\Plates\Engine" is a namespace, not a path.  You can include a "use" statement in your class for every imported class you want to use from that namespace if you want.

On their "installation" page [here](https://platesphp.com/getting-started/installation/) they show that you have to edit the composer.json file to load plates.  If you are unfamiliar with composer all you have to do is install it and run "composer update" in the folder with the composer.json file from the installation page and it will create the vendor folder for you with all the supporting files necessary to run Plates. It will place these files in a vendor folder which is why you need to require vendor/autoload.php.

Plates also assumes that the files in your template directory are php files and that is why they don't require a file extension on the parameter.  so 'template' and 'profile' refer directly to the template.php and profile.php files.

The essential idea behind templating is to separate your view and code.  Data is obtained by the code and passed into the view.  These template files represent the view and the data is passed into the templates via the associative array in the render function in the example.

Because Plates is a php based templating engine, the templates ARE php files.  So some php coding will be required to obtain the data from the model (the associative array) and for looping constructs and such.  What you want to achieve is to keep the code specific to only what is necessary to render the data in the html and nothing else.

The profile.php page and the template.php page are both "templates" The template.php file is useful if you are going to display a whole page but unnecessary if you just want to output an html element.  In the latter case the profile.php file in the example could be produced without the optional page 'layout'.

So what the 'render' function basically does is to load the php file specified by name and insert all the data from the associative array into that file according to its own code and optionally its associated layout template file and return the resulting html.

The class using the templates let's call it Presenter.php should have code something like this in it:

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use \League\Plates\Engine;

class Presenter {
    private $name;

    function __construct($name){
      $this->name = $name;
    }
    
    function render() {
      $templates = new Engine(__DIR__ . '/templates');
      echo $templates->render('profile', ['name' => $this->name]);
    }
}
```

and an index.php like this:

```
<?php
require(__DIR__ . '/Presenter.php');
$presenter = new Presenter('Jonathan');
$presenter->render();
```

...

where your file structure in your project directory looks something like this:

```
index.php
Presenter.php
templates/template.php
templates/profile.php
composer.json
composer.lock
vendor/...
```

That should get anyone interested in trying Plates started.